# tkinter- how to increase button's size repeatedly until reaching window's max size?

Tags: python, tkinter, animation

My code should do the following:
Start button starts to increase its size by one pixel when clicked
When reached to the window's size, it returns to its initial size. Can't really do the last part

```
from tkinter import *
def increase():
    global counter, x, y
    x += 1
    y += 1
    b1.config(padx=x, pady=y)
    b1.after(100, increase)

root=Tk()
x=5
y=2
# buttons
b1=Button(root, text="Start", bg="blue",
          command=increase, width=x, height=y)
b1.place(x=10,y=10)
b2=Button(root, text="Stop",  command=quit)
b2.place(x=10, y=260)

root.geometry("320x300")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can get the window size by using `root.winfo_width()` and `root.winfo_height()`.  Also get the button size by using `b1.winfo_width()` and `b1.winfo_height()`.  Now you have the required information to determine when to reset the button to its original size.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

from tkinter import *
def increase():
    global counter, x, y, root
    x += 3
    y += 3
    window_height=root.winfo_height()
    window_width=root.winfo_width()
    if x >= window_height:
        x=0
    if y >= window_width:
        y=0
    b1.config(padx=x/3, pady=y/3)
    b1.after(100, increase)

root=Tk()
x=5
y=2
# buttons
b1=Button(root, text="Start", bg="blue",
          command=increase, width=x, height=y)
b1.place(x=10,y=10)
b2=Button(root, text="Stop",  command=quit)
b2.place(x=10, y=260)

root.geometry("320x300")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.mainloop()
```

There are some differences on the button size, if you use width/height or padx/pady. I tried adapting the offset for the padx/pady.

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt this code using to your needs. It is not the best way to do it but it will do the work.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

count = 0


def reset_count():
    global count
    count = 0


def btn_size_changer():
    global count
    if count <= 21:
        if btn['width'] < 50 and btn['height'] < 40:
            btn['width'] += 2
            btn['height'] += 1
            root.after(100, btn_size_changer)
            count += 1
    else:
        if btn['width'] >= 7 and btn['height'] >= 3:
            btn['width'] -= 2
            btn['height'] -= 1
            root.after(100, btn_size_changer)
        else:
            reset_count()


btn = Button(root, text="Click ME", command=lambda: btn_size_changer(), width=6, height=3)
btn.pack(anchor=CENTER)


root.geometry('350x350')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It might be interesting to use the relx and rely parameter when you place your widgets.

relx and relx can be a value between 0 and 1. 1 ist 100% of the window size. 0 is 0% of the window size.

You could use that to set the size. It would not need to calculate if the windowsize is reached.